# Java - how to avoid this repetitive code

Tags: java

I am currently writing a Java program that displays values into an `AreaChart` and to do so I have an ArrayList with the name `dataList` from the generic type `AreaChartPair`.

Each `AreaChartPair` contains a X-Axis(String) value and a Y-Axis(Integer) value.

The X-Axis are dates and the Y-Axis is a counter and because all the data gets read from a file, the dates will be in a unsorted order. to sort them I use this function:

`dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing(AreaChartPair::getXAxisStringValue));`

Which is not completely solving my issue, since it will only compare the first few alphanumeric characters (i.e `02.09.2030` would come after `01.01.2000`, because `02` comes after `01`)

To solve this problem I simply reversed the date from `dd.mm.yyyy` to `yyyy.mm.dd`, sorted the list with the function above and afterwards reversed the string back to `dd.mm.yyyy`

My Question now is how I can simplify this block of code, since it is repetitive:

```
//replaces the current data with the reversed string
for (int index = 0; index < dataList.size(); index++) { 
    dataList.set(index, new AreaChartPair(model.reverseDate(dataList.get(index).getXAxisStringValue()),
        dataList.get(index).getYAxisIntegerValue()));
}

//sorts the data
dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing(AreaChartPair::getXAxisStringValue));

//reverses the string back to normal, so it can be displayed
for (int index = 0; index < dataList.size(); index++) {
    dataList.set(index, new AreaChartPair(model.reverseDate(dataList.get(index).getXAxisStringValue()),
        dataList.get(index).getYAxisIntegerValue()));
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a custom comparator that does the reversed compare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter way to perform the sorting is to do the reversing on the fly. The string could also be parsed to a real date object, to make it cleaner, but that requires catch blocks and dateformatter objects, so I won't write that code here.

```
dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing(AreaChartPair::getXAxisStringValue, 
    (a, b) -> { 
        return model.reverseDate(a).compareTo(model.reverseDate(b)); 
}));
```

Comment: works like a charm :) but  I think you might have forgotten a closing brace at the end

Comment: That was just to check if you were paying attention ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps make a method out of it:

```
AreaChartPair areaChartPair = new AreaChartPair(model.reverseDate(dataList.get(index).getXAxisStringValue()),
            dataList.get(index).getYAxisIntegerValue());
public DataListType dataListSorter(DataListType datalist, AreaChartPair areaChartPair) {
    for (int index = 0; index < dataList.size(); index++) {
        dataList.set(index, areaChartPair);
    }
return dataList;
}

dataList = dataListSorter(dataList);
dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing(AreaChartPair::getXAxisStringValue));
dataList = dataListSorter(dataList);
```

Still repetitive, though. Probably most useful to do it this way if you're going to do this over and over again throughout your application.

Comment: This could be a valid solution to my problem. The only problem for me would be this line:  `.set(index, new AreaChartPair(...)` since the new AreaChartPair(...) would be hard coded, is there a way to make this more dynamic? I already tried parameterizing a `Object` type to the method, but couldnt create a new class instance out of it